# creating iPhone draggable objects

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to figure out how in the world do I create object instances (an image) and place them on the screen and have it draggable. I know how to draw an image (png) onto the screen, but how do I make it draggable?

Answer (score 1):

Create sublclasses of UIView where you override the touchesEnded method. Inside this method alter the coordinates of the view to match those of the most recent UITouch, and that will give you basic draggable views.